# notifyDataSetChanged() not being called when underlying Realm is changed using RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, realm

I have a set of data in a `Realm` that is displayed in a `RecyclerView` using a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`. Basically, I'll have 25 elements displayed in the `RecyclerView` -- if items are being inserted into the `Realm` for the first time there are no issues. It seems to work properly if the `Realm` isn't being added to shortly after all its data has been deleted because the issue only arises when I need to delete all the items in the Realm and then add a new `Collection` of items shortly afterwards.

What will happen is I will send an http request for the new items, and on receiving them, I'll delete all the items currently in the `Realm`, and then add the new ones, both in different transactions; I've also tried doing it in the same transaction.

The unexpected behavior is that the contents of the `RecyclerView` will flicker for a very brief moment, as if all the items are about to be rebound, and I can even see the data of the new items being shown for a split second, but then the contents of the `RecyclerView` just goes back to showing the previous data -- the data I know to be deleted from the `Realm`. I know it's deleted because if I interact with the `RecyclerView` after this flicker, even just a click on a static view, all the items will be instantly rebound and reflect the new items that have been added; as if notifyDataSetChanged() is finally being called.

This behavior isn't always exhibited. Most of the time the items are all deleted, the new ones are added, and it just works perfectly; no flicker. But as far as the user behavior goes when it works properly and when it doesn't, there is nothing different. The same thing can be done over and over again and sometimes it will work and other times it won't.

I've tried deleting the items using `mRealm.deleteAll()` and `mOrderedRealmList.deleteAllFromRealm()`. And I've tried adding the items to the collection using both `mRealm.insert(items)` and `mRealm.copyToRealm(items)`. I've also tried manually calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` only after the items are added, only after the items are all deleted, and after both events, but the issue still occurs.

Any idea on what could be causing this behavior?

This is the only code that is run that manipulates `Realm` data:

```
mRealm.beginTransaction();
mOrderedRealmCollection().deleteAllFromRealm();
mRealm.commitTransaction();
...
...
processing of new items...
...
...
mRealm.beginTransaction();
mRealm.insert(items);
mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

### Update:

When I delete all the items from the `Realm` and add the new items within the same transaction the unexpected behavior occurs more frequently. Also, I've noticed that when the changes are made in the same transaction and the issue occurs, sometimes there is no flicker, the `RecyclerView` just continues to display the old data, uninterrupted, but if I touch the `RecyclerView` anywhere, just like when the flicker *does* occur, all the items will be instantly rebound and reflect the new items that have been added.

### Update: How Adapter is Set Up

```
//in onCreate() method
mItems = mRealm.where(Item.class).findAllSorted("mIndex", Sort.ASCENDING);

//in onCreateView() method
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new MyRealmRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mItems));
```

### Update: Cancel Button onClick() Code

```
private void setListeners(){
        mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSearchEditText.clearFocus();
                mCancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCreateItemButton.setVisible(true);
                Toast.makeText(A_Main.this,"Cancel clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should do this operation in the same transaction.

Comment: Can you show where you set up your adapter? Are you using a RealmList or the results from Realm directly?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Doesn't matter. Issue occurs regardless of whether I use one transaction or two. I use the results from the Realm directly.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've added how the adapter is set up

Comment: I see no reason why this should happen; what thread is the transaction on?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the main thread

Comment: Try using `executeTransactionAsync()`, and as I said, do the operation in the same transaction instead of two transactions

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that's still not making it work. in the `onSuccess()` method I call `scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0)` on the `RecyclerView`'s `LayoutManager`, so after all the changes have been made i should be looking at the first item in the `RecyclerView`, but I'm not always. if i reset the realm, add the new items, and call `scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0)`, but the original items were already scrolled down, when it "flickers", the recyclerview will still be in the same position with the old items.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i don't think this is a problem with realm. because the weirdest thing is, if i click a button in my appbar when a flicker has occured, a button that does nothing to the recyclerview at all -- i'll the post the code in the update -- the recyclerview changes to show the correct items scrolled to the top like they should be. why would clicking this button, seemingly unrelated to the recyclerview at all, have any affect on it?