# Activity still being destroyed when keyboard is shown even though I've configured the activity to handle that configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I don't want my activity to be destroyed when the keyboard pops up or goes away, so I added the appropriate xml attributes in the android manifest; namely, `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden`. In [the android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) it says:

> you can declare that your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your activity....To declare that your activity handles a configuration change, edit the appropriate  element in your manifest file to include the android:configChanges attribute with a value that represents the configuration you want to handle.

However, it seems like the state of the views in the activity are still being saved and then restored when the keyboard is shown. Here is why:

In this particular fragment, when the keyboard pops up it means the user is about to make a search. When that search is executed new `Item` objects are received, any old `Item` objects in the fragment's recyclerview's adapter are deleted, the new ones are added, and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called -- which should trigger the viewholders to show the new items.

What happens instead is that the results are received, the results from any previous searches are removed from the adapter, the new results are added, but something funny happens with the viewholders. Sometimes they won't even change, and sometimes they change for like a split-second, but then revert back to whatever they were showing before that split-second change.

I know, by default, android saves the state of the views in an activity's view hierarchy whenever the activity is destroyed as a result of a configuration change, and then restores that saved state in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. That's what seems like is happening here:

The viewholders reflect particular items before the keyboard pops up, when the keyboard pops up the state of the viewholders are saved, then when the user finishes typing in the search and executes it, the items are received, the old items are deleted, the new items are added, `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called -- showing the new items for a moment --, but then the keyboard is hidden and `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called, reverting the viewholders back to what they were showing before the keyboard popped up.

If the state is being restored when the keyboard goes down, why is that when I set the `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden` attribute in my manifest for the corresponding activity?

Comment: The activity is not destroyed and recreated when the input method (soft keyboard) is displayed. `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden` [are for *physical keyboards*](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config), particularly on devices where those keyboards can be slid open or closed (e.g., BlackBerry PRIV).

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. so why are the viewholders' state being restored to the way they were before the soft keyboard popped up?

Comment: I have no idea. You have not provided a [mcve].

Comment: @CommonsWare i'm looking for an educated guess rather than a solution. thanks anyways though

Comment: I cannot really guess either. Set breakpoints or add log statements where you are manipulating these things and see what the stack traces tell you.

Comment: @CommonsWare the problem is that the majority of the time everything works properly, and when it doesn't work properly, there doesn't seem to be any clear indication of what it is -- it's a rather small amount of code that is manipulating these things (<10 lines). it seems like a race condition is at play, but i don't see how. i've provided more detail on the problem in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084859/notifydatasetchanged-not-being-called-when-underlying-realm-is-changed-using-r) i asked when i thought the issue was rooted in the `Realm` framework i'm using